# In Commerce, can I apply a discount only on a specific number of one product?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, discounts

I know that I can apply a discount if a specific number of products is ordered. I could also add a discount for a specific product, with a specific amount. But, am I able to create a discount with this conditions:

- Applies to entire product type
- A specific number of **one product** is added to the cart

So, if I set this discount for 3 products, but people buy 2 x PRODUCT A, 1 x PRODUCT B, it would not apply. If customers buy 3 x PRODUCT A, 2 x PRODUCT B, it would apply for product A.

I could probably fix it with a plugin, but is it possible out of the box? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the release notes from Commerce 1.2:
https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1323

It can only be given a minimum quantity of items now.

Comment: If i look into your question, i would create a discount coupon -> Conditions -> Add Products select Product A -> Minimum Purchase Quantity and Maximum Purchase Quantity set to 3 that would solve it.

If it works please upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a custom adjuster. Please refer the code snippet below.

Create a new adjuster and apply your logic here

```
// check each line item
foreach($lineItems as $lineItem)
{
....
<your business logic here
....
$discount_total = <amount>;
}

$order->baseDiscount = $order->baseDiscount - $discount_total;

$myAdjuster->type = "Custom discount";
$myAdjuster->name = "Group discount";
$myAdjuster->description = "Total of discount";
$myAdjuster->amount = -$discount_total;
$myAdjuster->orderId = $order->id;
//        //if your Adjuster affects lineItems rather than the total, you record the ids here
$myAdjuster->optionsJson = ['lineItemsAffected'=> null ];
$myAdjuster->included = false;

return [$myAdjuster];
```